# AC analysis with positive/negative current paths having different Impedances

Tags: diodes, ac, ltspice, frequency-response

I am simulating a spring-mass-damper circuit.
I want to see how various damping scenarios perform in the frequency domain. I have linear, progressive, and digressive scenarios working...

Now I want to see the effect of separating the compression and rebound damping circuit.

LTspice does not simulate diodes in AC analysis the way you would expect. I can approximate it with math for a very simple case. The solution involved a adding a dependent current source.

I want to make generalized solution for the case below that LTspice can calculate automatically for me so I can compare different damping scenarios easily. Is there a relatively painless way of doing this?

*Assume that Zpos & Zneg will have a smooth continuous transition across the 0v axis.

[image]

Comment: You can just use one damper and use `.STEP` to see the variations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SPICE, the AC analysis is a linear analysis. It is assumed that the excitation of the circuit is small enough not to produce nonlinear behavior.

If you want to simulate nonlinear behavior you must do a transient analysis.

In other SPICE-like simulators (ADS, for example) there may be other analysis options such as harmonic balance that can predict nonlinear behavior more efficiently than a transient analysis, but as far as I know these are not available in LTSpice.

Comment: dang. Transient takes forever and getting the phase and magnitude is not fun.

Comment: @Tony Can the FFT function in the Waveform Viewer help with that?